# Document Printed an Extra 9,940 Pages

Tags: errors, compiling, capacity

```
 TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<to be read again>
```

I have a book class document that has added thousands of extra pages. I have scoured the log files, but I cannot find the issue. It seems that the problem is not in the main.tex file, because when I `\include` certain files, they compile without issue. So, I think the issue is in some of the files I want to include. However, I have not been able to ascertain exactly what is causing the issue. Each of the files I want to include have the same layout, but there is obviously something amiss. I have attempted commenting out sections, but I have not had luck. Below is an excerpt of the errors.

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 7186) has occurred while \output is active [81] [82]) [83] [84] [85] [86] [87] [88] [89] [90] [91] [92] [93] [94] [95] [96] [97] [98] [99] [100] [101] [102] [103] [104] [105] [106] [107] [108] [109] [110] [111] [112] [113] [114] [115] [116] [117] [118] [119] [120] [121] [122] [123] [124] [125] [126] [127] [128] [129] [130] [131] [132] [133] [134] [135] [136] [137] [138] [139] [140] [141] [142] [143] [144] [145] [146] [147] [148] [149] [150] [151] [152] [153] [154] [155] [156] [157] [158] [159] [160] [161] [162] [163] [164] [165] [166] [167] [168] [169] [170] [171] [172] [173] [174] [175] [176] [177] [178] [179] [180] [181] [182] [183] [184] [185] [186] **This continues until pg. 10,042.**
```

This is the content of the main.tex file, if it is would be helpful. However, as I mentioned, this works flawlessly on certain files and not others.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setmainlanguage{syriac}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={DejaVu Serif Bold}]{Serto Antioch Bible}

% Make Counters for Chapters and Verses
\newcommand{\currbook}{}
\newcounter{mychapter}
\newcounter{bibver}
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}
\setcounter{bibver}{0}

% Make Bible Chapter and Verses
\newcommand{\mychaptermark}{}
\newcommand{\bibvermark}{}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mychapter}% Increment the mychapter counter
  \renewcommand{\mychaptermark}{#1}%
  %\chaptermark{#1 : \bibvermark}% Include the verse number in the chaptermark
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  {\centering{#1}}% Center the chapter title
}

\newcommand{\bibver}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{bibver}% Increment the bibver counter
  \extramarks{#1}{#1}% Set both left and right marks to #1
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{#1 }}~%
}


% Make Book Title in English and Syriac
\newcommand{\englishtitle}[1]{\centering\LR{#1}}
\newcommand{\syriactitle}[1]{\centering{#1}}

% Footnotes

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{~#1}}

\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{\leftmark} % if equal
{\leftmark--\rightmark}} % if not equal 

% Set the headheight and potentially adjust topmargin
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed

% Customize header using fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Clear previous header settings
\fancyhead[CO]{\englishtitle}
\fancyhead[CE]{ܐܓܪܬܐ ܕܝܘܚܢܢ ܫܠܝܚܐ}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark:\lastleftxmark –– \rightmark:\firstrightxmark} % Right on odd pages, Left on even pages


\begin{document}

% \include{04_Gospel of Matthew.tex}
%\include{05_Gospel of Mark.tex}
% \include{20_Titus.tex}
% \include{1John.tex}

\end{document}
```

At the end of the log file, there is the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<to be read again> 
                   \use_i:nnnn 
l.69 \include{04_Gospel of Matthew.tex}
```

However, I do not have the code `\use_i:nnnn` in my file. So, I do not know what it refers to.

Comment: Apparently you're stuck in a loop but there is no way to say how without seeing the code. How do the extra pages look? Are they empty or not? This might give an hint of where the loop starts.

Comment: my first try would be to remove your footnote redefinition.

Comment: They show the header, but the pages are blank. When troubleshooting, I first commented out the header. However, I received the same error. When I commented everything except the header, it compiled fine. 

I will try removing the footnote definition to see if it works.

Comment: I have commented out the footnote redefinition, but I have the same error.

Comment: well the loop begins around page 81 - 83 so check what is there.

Comment: I have looked again through the log file, and the error occurs 73 other times. The first occurrence is early in the file, but the output seems normal. At pages 81–83, there was nothing out of the ordinary. I have also attempted to comment out parts of the preamble, but nothing has fixed this problem.

Comment: As long as you cannot replicate the error in a form others can test it, there is not much we can do.

Comment: The `Underfull \vbox` aren't really errors and probably unrelated to the issue. But you already said that commenting out some parts doesn't stop the error, so keep doing that: delete stuff until the error goes away. Then you can isolate where the error comes from.

Comment: what is in the log after `<to be read again> ` it should show what is being read

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it says 
`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<to be read again> 
                   \use_i:nnnn 
l.69 \include{04_Gospel of Matthew.tex}
                                       
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.`

Comment: so it's `\use_i:nnnn` to be read again, but you should add that to a code block in your question, lines are lost in comments which makes error messages very hard to follow

Comment: recent  latex will try to correct, but you should never use `.tex` in `\include`, so try `\include{04_Gospel of Matthew}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I received the same error after removing the `.tex.` However, I am at a loss about what `\use_i:nnnn` means.

Comment: it's a expl3 command that uses one of four arguments. but you should be able to make an example, just delete everything you can while getting this error

Answer (score 3):

You have something similar to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\par{\vskip0pt}

x\vskip

\end{document}
```

which makes terminal output

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.7 x\vskip
           
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

note the `<to be read again>` message shows which token is to be read  (`\vskip` here) but you have not shown the full message or shown any code that produces the error.

Comment: I believe that what David is saying, is that you have defined a macro in terms of itself, so it creates an infinite loop. The `x\vskip` is automatically interpreted as `x\vskip\par`. But since you redefined `\par` to include `\vskip`, that becomes `x\vskip\vskip\par`, which ten becomes `x\vksip\vskip\vskip\par`, ... to infinity.

Comment: @rallg actually `x\par\vskip`  vskip in hmode inserts `\par` and then _is read again_

Comment: Thanks, David. Same effect, but more accurate explanation.

Comment: @rallg you would typically get a different error from a simple recursive macro such as  `\def\foo{\foo.}  \foo`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a conflict between the two footnote packages. I am not sure why the packages would interact properly in certain cases but not others. After commenting out random sections and getting the document to compile and then struggling to get it to recompile, I decided to comment out the footnote packages. Sure enough, this solved it.

Now, my preamble does not include `\usepackage{dblfnote}`. So, while the package can work with `\usepackage{footmisc}` in some cases (apparently?), it is best not to use them together to avoid any cryptic error messages and thousands of unnecessary pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setmainlanguage{syriac}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={DejaVu Serif Bold}]{Serto Antioch Bible}

% Make Counters for Chapters and Verses
\newcommand{\currbook}{}
\newcounter{mychapter}
\newcounter{bibver}
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}
\setcounter{bibver}{0}

% Make Bible Chapter and Verses
\newcommand{\mychaptermark}{}
\newcommand{\bibvermark}{}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mychapter}% Increment the mychapter counter
  \renewcommand{\mychaptermark}{#1}%
  %\chaptermark{#1 : \bibvermark}% Include the verse number in the chaptermark
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  {\centering{#1}}% Center the chapter title
}

\newcommand{\bibver}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{bibver}% Increment the bibver counter
  \extramarks{#1}{#1}% Set both left and right marks to #1
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{#1 }}~%
}


% Make Book Title in English and Syriac
\newcommand{\englishtitle}[1]{\centering\LR{#1}}
\newcommand{\syriactitle}[1]{\centering{#1}}

% Footnotes

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{~#1}}

\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{\leftmark} % if equal
{\leftmark--\rightmark}} % if not equal 

% Set the headheight and potentially adjust topmargin
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed

% Customize header using fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Clear previous header settings
\fancyhead[CO]{\englishtitle}
\fancyhead[CE]{ܐܓܪܬܐ ܕܝܘܚܢܢ ܫܠܝܚܐ}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark:\lastleftxmark –– \rightmark:\firstrightxmark} % Right on odd pages, Left on even pages


\begin{document}

% \include{04_Gospel of Matthew.tex}
%\include{05_Gospel of Mark.tex}
% \include{20_Titus.tex}
% \include{1John.tex}

\end{document}
```